# Find all user in table A that are also in Table B

Tags: sql

I have table A with fields user1 and user2 and table B with user3 and user4 pairs.

I want to be able to find any rows from table A where the user1/user2 combination is also in table B.

The order doesn't matter. For example table A with user1=Mike, user2=Joe would match table B with user3=Joe and user4=Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.user1, a.user2 from a, b 
where (a.user1 == b.user3 and a.user2 == b.user4)
or (a.user1 = b.user4 and a.user2 = b.user3);
```

Comment: See: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins - you should stop using that legacy method of just comma-separating a list of tables. Use **proper** ANSI JOINs instead!

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably just use an explicit `or` in a join:

```
select user1, user2 
      from tableA join tableB on 
          (user1=user3 and user2=user4) or 
          (user1=user4 and user2=user3)
```

...but take it with a grain of salt. I've been accused of over-using joins, probably with at least a little reason.

Comment: wow, both submitted at the same time, too bad SO doesn't show the # of seconds too ;-) I'll pick the other one because it's more plain vanilla and because James has a lot less points ;-) Thanks a bunch for  the quick reply!

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the "answered xx minutes ago", it'll show the exact time of each submission. He was 11 seconds ahead of me.